# Spark UDF for sequence Generator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

All,

I am trying to create UDF for spark dataframe, which will be used for generating the unique ID per row.
To ensure uniqueness, I am relying on: ID Generator will take "epoch value of timestamp ( bigint ) + "unique Source ID passed as argument + randomNumber 5 digit

I have 2 questions :

1. how to include monotonically_increasing_id() during id generation function "idGenerator"
2. while using the UDF, failing for below error :

```
    error:Type mismatch;
    found : String(SRC_")
    required : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
            df.withColumn("rowkey",SequenceGeneratorUtil.GenID("SRC_") )
```

Please provide any pointer ...

```
Object SequenceGeneratorUtil extends Serializable {

    val random = new scala.util.Random
    val start = 10000
    val end = 99999

    //CustomEpochGenerator - this is custom function to generate the epoch value for current timestamp in milliseconds
    // ID Generator will take "epoch value of timestamp ( bigint ) + "unique Source ID passed as argument + randomNumber 5 digit
    def idGenerator(SrcIdentifier: String ): String = SrcIdentifier + CustomEpochGenerator.nextID.toString + (start + random.nextInt((end - start) + 1)).toString // + monotonically_increasing_id ( not working )

    val GenID = udf[String, String](idGenerator __)

}

val df2 = df.withColumn("rowkey",SequenceGeneratorUtil.GenID("SRC_") )
```

Comment: why don't you just use `monotonically_increasing_id()`, it is already unique?

Answer (score 1):

Change below function

```
def idGenerator(SrcIdentifier: String ): String = SrcIdentifier + CustomEpochGenerator.nextID.toString + (start + random.nextInt((end - start) + 1)).toString // + monotonically_increasing_id ( not working )
```

to below function, added `mId` extra parameter in `idGenerator` to hold `monotonically_increasing_id` value.

```
def idGenerator(SrcIdentifier: String,mId: Long): String = SrcIdentifier + CustomEpochGenerator.nextID.toString + (start + random.nextInt((end - start) + 1)).toString + mId
```

Change below `udf`

```
val GenID = udf[String, String](idGenerator __)
```

to

```
val GenID = udf(idGenerator _)
```

**failing for below error :**
error:Type mismatch; found : String(SRC_") required : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
df.withColumn("rowkey",SequenceGeneratorUtil.GenID("SRC_") )

Because `SequenceGeneratorUtil.GenID` udf is expecting value of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Column` but you are passing value `SRC_` is of type `String`.

To fix this issue, Use `lit` function.

```
df.withColumn("rowkey",SequenceGeneratorUtil.GenID(lit("SRC_")) )
```

Change below `withColumn`

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("rowkey",SequenceGeneratorUtil.GenID("SRC_") )
```

to

```
val df2 = df
            .withColumn(
                "rowkey",
                SequenceGeneratorUtil.GenID(
                    lit("SRC_"), // using lit function to pass static string.
                    monotonically_increasing_id
                )
            )
```